# Displaying SQL Data on a ASP.Net Core Application with Multiple Array List<>

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I found a tutorial on how to pass one array list with sql data in it through "public IActionResult Index()" but I need multiple Lists with data from multiple sql query statements passed through my index.cshtml page. I am using ASP.Net Core MVC. I have multiple Models which I will show and the HomeController. I can show the cshtml too. I tried to pass all the query statements through one List<> but it would print out multiple of the first query statement  empty.

CampaignCreat.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CampaignReportDemo.Models
{
public class CampaignCreat
{
    public string CampaignCreative { get; set; }
}
}
```

WebBrowser.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CampaignReportDemo.Models
{
public class WebBrowser
{
    public string SoftwareName { get; set; }
    public string number1 { get; set; }
}
}
```

DeviceClick.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CampaignReportDemo.Models
 {
   public class DeviceClick
 {
    public string HardwareType { get; set; }
    public string number { get; set; }
   }
}
```

CampaignSummary.cs

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    namespace CampaignReportDemo
 {
  public class CampaignSummary
{
    public string FriendlyFrom { get; set; }
    public string BroadcastDate { get; set; }
    public string EmailsOrdered { get; set; }
    public string Opens { get; set; }
    public string Clicks { get; set; }
   
   
   
   }
 }
```

HomeController.cs

```
using CampaignReportDemo.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

    namespace CampaignReportDemo.Controllers
 {
 public class HomeController : Controller
 {
    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand();
    SqlDataReader dr;
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
    List<CampaignSummary> CampaignSummaries = new List<CampaignSummary>();
    List<DeviceClick> DeviceClicks = new List<DeviceClick>();/*I need these Lists to pass 
    through IActionResult Index()*/
    List<WebBrowser> WebBrowsers = new List<WebBrowser>();      
    List<CampaignCreat> CampaignCreats = new List<CampaignCreat>();
    
    private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;

    public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        con.ConnectionString = CampaignReportDemo.Properties.Resources.ConnectionString;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        FetchData();
      /*I can get one list through but not multiple*/
 
        return View(CampaignSummaries);
    }
    private void FetchData()
    {
        if(CampaignSummaries.Count > 0 && DeviceClicks.Count > 0 && WebBrowsers.Count > 0 && 
           CampaignCreats.Count > 0 )
        {
            CampaignSummaries.Clear();
            DeviceClicks.Clear();
            WebBrowsers.Clear();
            CampaignCreats.Clear();
        }
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            com.Connection = con;
            com.CommandText = "select FriendlyFrom, EmailsOrdered, BroadcastDate, Opens, 
                 Clicks from CampaignResults where CampaignId = 24896;" +
                ";select HardwareType, count(*) as number from User_Details Group by 
                   HardwareType;" +
                "select SoftwareName, count(*) as number1 from User_Details Group By 
                 SoftwareName;" +
                "select  CampaignCreative from CampaignAdCopy where CampaignId = 24896;";
            dr = com.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                CampaignSummaries.Add(new CampaignSummary() { FriendlyFrom = 
              dr["FriendlyFrom"].ToString(), BroadcastDate = dr["BroadcastDate"].ToString(), 
             EmailsOrdered = dr["EmailsOrdered"].ToString()
                , Opens = dr["Opens"].ToString(), Clicks = dr["Clicks"].ToString()});
            }
            dr.NextResult();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                DeviceClicks.Add(new DeviceClick() { HardwareType = 
               dr["HardwareType"].ToString(), number = dr["number"].ToString() });
            }
            dr.NextResult();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                WebBrowsers.Add(new WebBrowser() { SoftwareName = 
              dr["SoftwareName"].ToString(), number1 = dr["number1"].ToString() });
            }
            dr.NextResult();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
               CampaignCreats.Add(new CampaignCreat() { CampaignCreative = 
         dr["CampaignCreative"].ToString() });
            }
            con.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
    public IActionResult Privacy()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
    public IActionResult Error()
    {
        return View(new ErrorViewModel { RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? 
        HttpContext.TraceIdentifier });
      }
   }
 }
```

Index.cshtml

```
 @{
      ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
  }
  <section>

  <table id="first">
    <tr>
        <th colspan="2">Campaign Report</th>
    </tr>
    @{
        if (Model != null)
        {
            foreach (var Data in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>Name:</td>
                    <td>@Data.FriendlyFrom</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Date/Time:</td>
                    <td>@Data.BroadcastDate</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Quantity:</td>
                    <td>@Data.EmailsOrdered</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Opens:</td>
                    <td>@Data.Opens</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Opens%:</td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Clicks:</td>
                    <td>@Data.Clicks</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Clicks%:</td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
            }
        }
        }

</table>




<table>
    <tr>
        <th colspan="2">Device Stats By Click</th>
    </tr>
           @{ 
               if (Model != null)
               {
                   foreach (var Data in Model)
                   {
                <tr>
                    <td>@Data.HardwareType</td>
                    <td>@Data.number</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                   }
               }
               }
            </table>
   </section>
     <aside valign="bottom">
     <table>
    <tr>
        <th colspan="2">Campaign Creative</th>
        
            @{
                if (Model != null)
                {
                    foreach (var Data in Model)
                    {
          <tr>
                    <td>@Data.CampaignCreative</td>
                </tr>
                    }
                }
                }
            </table>
        </aside>
           <article>
               <table>
              <tr>
                   <th colspan="2">Web Browser Stats By Click</th>
               </tr>
            @{ 
                if (Model != null)
                {
                    foreach (var Data in Model)
                    {
                    <tr>
                                        <td>@Data.SoftwareName  @Data.number1</td>
                     
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                        }
                    }
                }

                </table>
        </article>
```

Comment: Have you considered defining a new class that contains properties of each of your List types, and then passing that into your view? We generally call such a class a "view model"

Comment: Your problem is that you are not passing the correct model to your view. If you need more than one model, create a new container class and use that instead.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a ViewModel class with properties for the three lists that you want to show on your page.

In your index() method create a new instance of that and load up the data and set them to the properties, and then pass that viewmodel object to the View() method.

That class then becomes the @Model and you access the three list properties from it for each for your for loops (@Model.CampaignSummaries for example).

Don't forget to change the model type defintion at the top of the cshtml page to you new viewModel class type.